# Как указать путь к файлу, который находится рядом с файлом .exe

Tags: c#, path

Имеется .exe файл который лежит в папке на рабочем столе.

[image: папка]

Я хочу указать **путь к файлу** "Список целевых компонентов Р-7.xlsx" или "Список целевых компонентов Р-8.xlsx" в программе, т.е. я хочу чтобы **при запуске** программа открывала файл например "Список целевых компонентов Р-7.xlsx" **из папки ChromaWrite**, и чтобы путь был **не статичен**,а например при **перемещении папки** ChromaWrite в другую директорию открывался файл "Список целевых компонентов Р-7.xlsx" который лежит в рабочей директории с ChromaWrite.exe

Какие будут идеи и советы?

Comment: Указать не абсолютный, а относительный путь.

Comment: Можно так http://stackoverflow.com/a/48418253/5727271

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` - возвращает текущую рабочую директорию

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, спасибо за ответы, вы мне помогли. Можете оформить как ответ на вопрос

Comment: Ну а по поводу комментариев выше (относительный путь и текущая раб. директория) - это как по мне неверное решения, ибо если запустить например .exe файл через консоль, просто прописав `путь до exe/моя программа.exe`, то рабочей директорией будет либо `C:\Windows`, либо директория пользователя. Будет ли там файл нужный вам? Я не думаю... Также рабочий каталог меняется и при помощи простого ярлыка. Все конечно зависит от того, что в итоге вы хотите, но мой вам совет - используйте пункт 4 из помеченного мной как дубликат вопроса.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо Вам за рекомендации. Я использовал Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). Программа моя пускается через .exe файл из папки с программой. Я по шагам отследил, программа делает то, что надо. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Если это приложение чисто для вас или узкого круга людей, то можете и оставить так, если для публики, то смотрите сами, потом не приходите сюда с вопросом "Почему не находит файл?")

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , да это программа для узкого круга людей, которые через консоль программы не открывают) Даже если я захочу через консоль открыть программу, я же наберу по идее ту же самую директорию, по этому должно работать.

Comment: Если вы не зададите рабочий каталог, где находится ваш файл, то нет, работать не будет. Попробуйте просто откройте консоль и напишите `[путь до программы]/ChromaWrite.exe` и посмотрите на результат) Что бы этого избежать, надо писать `cd [путь до программы]` и только потом писать `ChromaWrite.exe` и вот `cd` вам задаст нужный каталог. Ну или попробуйте через ярлык заменить [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyxWw.png) значение на любое другое и все, ваше приложение нерабочее. В общем, мое дело предупредить, а уже вам решать, устранять этот недочет или "и так сойдет".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я через cd сразу сделал и разницы не увидел, а просто директорию не прописал. Для моей программки и так сойдёт честно говоря, но всё же чисто из любопытства, всё же мне интересно как побороть эту неувязку, что Вы посоветуете?

Comment: Сделайте пустой консольный проект и напишите там что то, на подобие [этого](https://pastebin.com/3ckcKvLW). Далее сделайте в корне, рядом с .exe файлов любой другой файл, который будет проверяться на наличие и укажите его имя в коде. Скомпилируйте проект и запустите, выдаст везде `true`, так? Ок, запускайте консоль, пишите `[полный путь до приложения]/МоеПриложение.exe` и жмите enter (у меня это `"D:\Projects\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\TestedConsoleApp.exe"`). И тут вы сразу увидите, что `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` выдал не то, что надо и файл нашло только по одному пути.

Comment: Как решить - я уже пометил вопрос дубликатом, там все об этом сказано. Нужно вам это или нет - решать вам, мое как я уже говорил, только предупредить...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за помощь. Пометьте его ещё раз клоном, сейчас нет такой пометки

Comment: Мое самое первое сообщение в комментариях тут, на буржуйском которое (спасибо новым обновлениям). Участник только 1 раз может дать голос вопросу, так что да, я не могу кинуть повторно дубликат)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Используйте относительные пути.

Примеры:

```
// Считает текст из файла file.txt который лежит рядом с программой
var file = File.ReadAllText("./file.txt");
```

```
// Считает текст из файла file.txt который лежит в папке test1 рядом с программой
var file = File.ReadAllText("./test1/file.txt");
```

Comment: `который лежит рядом с программой` - скорей, "который лежит в рабочей директории", а эта директория может отличаться от пути до программы.